# how do i put this dictionary values in a new column of a dataframe called 'municipality'?

Tags: python, data-science

i have extracted these values from a dictionary called 'mun_dict', now i want to take this extracted values and then put them in a new column of my dataframe, the column has 200 indexes but the values in the mun_dict are only 7.

I want to put the mun_dict values in the new column and then use 'np.nan' when a municipality is not found.

I tried this but it returned this error: 'Length of values (2) does not match length of index (200)'

This is the code i tried,

```
mun_dict.values()

twitter_df['municipality'] =[mun_dict.values(), np.nan]

twitter_df[['municipality']]
```

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py in require_length_match(data, index)
    529     """
    530     if len(data) != len(index):
--> 531         raise ValueError(
    532             "Length of values "
    533             f"({len(data)}) "

ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (200)
```

Comment: So, you tried to do this, and then what? It doesn't work at all? Do you get any exception or error message? Please add more informations

Comment: i have edited it, please check it out... please make it easy for me, i don't know how to go about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will put the values in the first 7 rows and the rest will be np.nan

```
twitter_df['municipality'] = list(mun_dict.values()) + list(np.nan * np.ones(len(twitter_df)-len(mun_dict.values())))
```